# using cp command to copy one set of files to another set (with same names) without overwrite and with renaming

Tags: linux, file, unix, copy, cp

Say I have a bunch of files in folder A:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
...
```

And a bunch of files in folder B, with the same names.

I want to move all the files from folder B into folder A, without losing any files. This means that some files need to be renamed. E.g., to 1cp.txt, 2cp.txt, 3cp.txt, ...

As I understand it, using

```
cp folderB/*.txt folderA/
```

will overwrite all files in folder A. Whereas, if I use the -n flag, this means that nothing will be copied, because -n prevents overwriting.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this copy and rename procedure, so that all files from both folders are retained?

Comment: Does it need to be a one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-b` (backup each existing file). `--backup` accepts arguments to control behavior.
Otherwise you can create a bit more lines and check for your files in a more elaborated script.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can rename it.

```
$ rename -n 's/\d{5}(\d{3})\.JPG$/BeachPics_$1\.jpg/' *.JPG
00000123.JPG renamed as BeachPics_123.jpg
00000124.JPG renamed as BeachPics_124.jpg
00000125.JPG renamed as BeachPics_125.jpg
```

and then copy it.

```
cp folderB/*.txt folderA/
```